# What's the origin of -> in Rust function definition return types?

Tags: rust

Rust uses colons to separate identifiers from types, like in

```
let x: u8 = 1;
```

However, for function return types -> is used instead. Example:

```
fn f() -> u8 { ... }
```

One might expect it to use a colon here as well:

```
fn f(): u8 { ... }
```

While using arrows has some precedence (e.g. in Haskell), I'm curious about the historical reason behind this choice. In addition, I'm also curious if it's a purely aesthetic reason or if using an arrow has some  technical reason e.g. in simplifying parsing.

Comment: The type of `x` is `u8`; the type of `f` is *not* `u8`.

Comment: This is convention. Many languages use this. C++ has the trailing return type. OCaml has a similar function signature style. It just is.

Comment: One _possible_ reason is that in mathematics, arrows indicate mappings from a domain to a codomain. For example, `f : X -> Y`; `f` is a mapping of the set `X` to the set `Y`.

Comment: Interesting old question, and that no one mentioned TypeScript which does use `:` to denote return types. Because functions names must have parenthesis there is no ambiguity: the type of `f(): number` is "a function which returns a number.

Answer (score 15):

Well, I’m only guessing, but I’d say that the reason is purely aesthetic.
`:` is often pronounced as “has the type”, while `->` is pronounced as “to”. So `f: fn(i32) -> i32` means “f *has the type* of functions from `i32` *to* `i32`”.

Basically, there are two contexts where the return value of a function can be mentioned:

1. Function item declaration:

   ```
   fn foo(x: i32) -> i32 {
     …
   }
   ```
2. Assignment of a function to a variable with explicit type:

   ```
   let f: fn(x: i32) -> i32 = foo;
   ```

While using colon instead of arrow wouldn’t hurt readability in the first case, it would definitely do so in the second one. And it makes perfect sense to have the same symbol in both contexts.

The ultimate origin of this arrow is [Simply Typed Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) where this arrow is used as the function type constructor. From there it came to Haskell, Scala (well, not exactly, they use `=>`) and other languages.

Comment: I think it's important to note that if you used `: T` to denote the return type, this would imply the "type" of `f` is `T`. Rust functions aren't first-class objects, though; they have no type. Closures are the exception to this (as they are anonymous).

Comment: @erip How do you mean? Rust functions do have [types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#function-types).

Comment: I stand corrected. However, the conclusion is the same: functions' return types cannot be denoted by a colon.

Comment: @erip Well, I don’t think that replacing all the arrows with colons in the grammar would screw it or make it more difficult to parse. You do not specify the type of the declared item after the `fn` keyword, so there is no ambiguity. But I agree that this would be way more difficult to read for a human.

Comment: It is highly likely that the function return type is denoted by arrow because it is like that in ML family of languages, in particular, in OCaml, which was used for the first versions of Rust compiler.

Comment: This was discussed on the old mailing list: [whole thread](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-July/thread.html#5026), [graydon's response](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-July/005042.html) (basically exactly what you said: good guess!)